Raf'aulyadain of Ali Ibn Abi talib
I have seen many issues of dispute among scholars of islam of ahlul sunnah in case of rafauddain But the hadeeth of Ali ibn abi talib In Ibn Majah 717 abu dawood 744,761 tirmidhi 3423....the all given hadith is Hasan [Sahih] but some other people say it's daef because of the Ravi Abdur rahaman ibn abi zinad what's the real source of the hadith
